# Axios - How to get the Cookies from the response?

Tags: node.js, http, authentication, cookies, axios

I need to get an authentication cookie from a website, while performing my request using Axios.

```
var axios = require('axios');
const authentication = async(login, password) => {
    var data = `MYPAYLOAD${login}[...]${password}`;

    var config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://mywebsite.com/login.aspx',
        headers: { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        data : data,
    };

    try {
        return await axios(config, {withCredentials: true});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error: cannot authenticate...')
    }
}

const init = async() => {

    const login = 'LOGIN';
    const password = 'PASSWORD';

    const response = await authentication(login, password);
    console.log(response);

}

init()
```

I'm receiving some Cookies that I need, but the one including the auth token is missing.

If I use exactly the same settings in Postman, I'm receiving the AUTH_TOKEN I'm looking for.

Where am I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: run a `tcpdump`/Wireshark, capture the Postman request and the one sent by axios and post the results